# How to put just date from date time in unique constraint in Django

Tags: django, model

I have two columns in a Django model. `name` and `start_date_time`. I have the requirement of to make `name` and `date` unique in this model. I am able to make `name` and `start_date_time` unique but I have no idea at all how to make just `date` (not `time`) and `name` unique.

So below example should not be a valid. It should throw error while saving second entry.

```
name  | start_date_time
------------------------
name1 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00
name1 | 2017-01-01 11:11:11
```

Please guide me in right direction how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to use `unique_together`, then you need a field that just has the date. Easiest thing might be to have two fields -- `datefield` and `timefield` -- instead of a single`datetimefield`.